# Make an Optional expression throw an error if it was present but didn't match

Tags: python, dsl, pyparsing

I'm using the PyParsing library to define my own SQL-like DSL. Here is the relevant part from it:

```
argument_separator = pp.Suppress(",")
brace_open = pp.Suppress("(")
brace_close = pp.Suppress(")")

argument_string = pp.quotedString.setParseAction(pp.removeQuotes)

keyword_author = pp.CaselessKeyword("author")
keyword_date = pp.CaselessKeyword("date")

function_matches = pp.CaselessLiteral("matches")
function_in = pp.CaselessLiteral("in")
function_between = pp.CaselessLiteral("between")

author_matches = pp.Group(keyword_author + function_matches + brace_open +
                          pp.Group(argument_string) +
                          brace_close)
author_in = pp.Group(keyword_author + function_in + brace_open +
                     pp.Group(argument_string + pp.OneOrMore(argument_separator + argument_string)) +
                     brace_close)
date_between = pp.Group(keyword_date + function_between + brace_open +
                        pp.Group(argument_string + argument_separator + argument_string) +
                        brace_close)

expression = pp.Optional(author_matches | author_in) & pp.Optional(date_between)
```

**Examples:**

```
# These all match:
author in("Lukas", "Timo", "Michae1")
author matches("hallo@welt.de")
date between("two days ago", "today")
author matches("knuth") date between("two days ago", "today")

# This does (and should) not.
date between(today)
```

The last expression doesn't match but doesn't throw an exception either. It just returns an empty result.

**My goal:** A "query" in my DSL consists of multiple expressions of the form

```
[column] [operator]([parameter],...)
```

No doublets are allowed. Furthermore, all possible expressions are optional (so an empty query is perfectly legal).

**My problem:** The current approach doesn't throw an error if one of these expressions is malformed. Because they are all `Optional`, if they don't match exactly, they're just ignored. That is confusing to the user, since he doesn't get an error, but the result is wrong.

So, what I need is an expression that is optional (so can be completely omitted), but will throw a `ParseException`, if it was malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `parseAll` to `True` when parsing each line, e.g. `expression.parseString(line, parseAll=True)`. This will throw a `ParseException` exception if the entire line wasn't matched.

See [the "Using the pyparsing module" page](http://www.cnd.mcgill.ca/~ivan/hw2/hw1/doc/pyparsing/HowToUsePyparsing.html#classes-in-the-pyparsing-module) for a bit more info.